# How to add authentication token to global variable in postman from RESTAPI (Go)

Tags: postman

I am writing a RESTAPI in Go, using Mux and GORM, I have been able to generate the token and then return it, but I am struggling to find a way to update the global variable set in Postman.

I am able to add the token to the `Authorization` header, but once I send another request, it gets replaced with `null` defeating the purpose of JWT authentication.

Here is the test I've got in Postman

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if (jsonData["token"] === null) {
    // ...
} else {
    postman.setGlobalVariable("token", jsonData["token"]);
}
```

As you can see I tried to run an `if` statement to essentially do nothing if there isn't a token, but it doesn't seem to work, the authorization header keeps getting set to `null`

Here is the handler in Go

```
func LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var user User
    db.DB.Where("email = ?", r.FormValue("email")).Find(&user)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if user.checkPassword(r.FormValue("password")) {
        token, err := user.generateJWT()
        w.Header().Set("Authorization", token.Token)
        if err != nil {
            customHTTP.NewErrorResponse(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, "Error: "+err.Error())
            return
        }
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(&token)

    } else {
        fmt.Println(user)
        customHTTP.NewErrorResponse(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, "Password incorrect")
        return
    }
}
```

and here is the function that generates the JWT token:

```
func (u User) generateJWT() (JWTToken, error) {
    signingKey := []byte(os.Getenv("JWT_SECRET"))
    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, jwt.MapClaims{
        "exp":     time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 1 * 1).Unix(),
        "user_id": int(u.ID),
        "name":    u.Name,
        "email":   u.Email,
    })
    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(signingKey)
    return JWTToken{tokenString}, err
}
```

Also here is the `JWTMiddleWare` function:

```
func JWTMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        tokenString := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        if len(tokenString) == 0 {
            customHTTP.NewErrorResponse(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, "Authentication failure")
            return
        }
        tokenString = strings.Replace(tokenString, "Bearer ", "", 1)
        claims, err := VerifyToken(tokenString)
        if err != nil {
            customHTTP.NewErrorResponse(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, "Error verifying JWT token: "+err.Error())
            return
        }

        userId := strconv.FormatFloat(claims.(jwt.MapClaims)["user_id"].(float64), 'g', 1, 64)
        r.Header.Set("userId", userId)
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

I am essentially just looking for a way to store the token in the authentication header so that it can be cross referenced later in the code when trying to visit a protected handler.

Comment: If I didn't misunderstand your question, this is how normally done, give and take! 1) Call `POST /token` (*example*) endpoint so it returns a JSON body where `token` field present. 2) Add this piece of script `if (pm.response.code == 200) { var jsonData = pm.response.json(); pm.globals.set("token", "token");}` to `Tests` tab. 3) Use `{{token}}` in `Authorization` tab of other endpoints. - I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.